# Running Magento on G-WAN

Tags: php, zend-framework, g-wan

So it seems that the g-wan supports PHP as I could check on the site, but the docs are very light. I could test a single .php file, but running magento doesn't work.

Also from what I read, the way to tries to match routes to files, would be a problem for something built on Zend with many rewrites, wouldnt it?

Is there a way to get it working or is it still work in progress?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an important point here.

It's like asking why `Apache Tomcat` can't run `ORACLE GlassFish` applications out-of-the box, or why `Nginx` configuration files won't work for `Apache`.

As a `ZEND frameworks application`, the `Magento` packages expects its host server to support specific configuration files, specific framework features, a specific directory for PHP source code files, etc.

While G-WAN supports the `PHP` language, it is not a `ZEND frameworks` clone.

For example, G-WAN does not use configuration files at all, unlike `ZEND frameworks applications`.

And G-WAN being able to run *15 scripted languages*, it is simply impossible (and pointless) to emulate all the specificities of all the language frameworks (that's hundreds of different proprietary sets of thousands of features and configuration specificities).

G-WAN's goal was not to clone any Web framework.

G-WAN was developed to make our life at TWD easier (more productive) and to extract more from the hardware resources (especially the parallelism of multicore systems).